# Next.js server side component request, how to send my cookie token?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

My Next.js is 14.1.0 and I'm using App router.

```
async function Page() {
  const dataPromise: Promise<any> = getData();
  const data = await dataPromise;
  console.log('data: ', data);
  return (
    ....
  );
}
```

`getData` is a simple function which I make a request to the Django rest API. If there is a token in the cookie, requests can be made to protected services.

When I make the same request on the client side, the response is 200 (OK) because I have a token. However, when I make a request on the server side, I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

I guess the server side does not see my token when I make a request. How can I solve this problem? How do I use my token for server side fetching?

Comment: The problem basically is that you have two domains, one on which Django is running and another on which Next JS is running. Your cookies for authentication are stored on the users browser for the domain on which Django is running. Your Next JS server will not get these cookies when the users browser makes a request to it.

Comment: But my request to django is a rest api request. I got to token from django rest api and i hold it in cookies. When i do the rest api request from client side with the same logic it works because my getData function is creating axios and adding my token to header like this:
const accessToken = Cookies.get('access_token');
config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
But when i use the same function on server side fetching its not working. Maybe i need to write some middleware but i dont know how

Comment: You are right in that server doesn't have access to cookies. You might need to add the token to the `getData` function as a parameter and fetch it in the client then pass it along.

Comment: getData function already adding the token to header for fetching and for the client side fetching it works perfectly but i want to make a server side fetching with django rest api accessToken.

Comment: I believe you are not getting the token on the server because your library is working with browser APIs, and not looking in the HTTP headers. Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a request from the browser to get the page, your cookies are sent along. You can grab your token using the [`cookies()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) function of Next.js and pass it to `getData` inside which you set the `Authorization` header:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default async function Page() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessToken = cookieStore.get("access_token");
  const data = await getData(accessToken);
  return "....";
}
```

The `Cookies.get('access_token')` you said you are using in the comments is I guess working with [browser APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/get) and not looking inside HTTP headers.